# XML inside of XML Node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have XML like the following:

```
  <CallStep>
    <StepXaml>
      <StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:CallTracker.Library.UserControls.BaseUserControls;assembly=CallTracker.Library">
        <uc:LabelValueControl Label="TestLabel" Value="356733" />
      </StackPanel>
    </StepXaml>
</CallStep>
```

that I would then like to store in a property

```
[XmlElement("StepXaml")]
public object StepXaml { get; set; }
```

I am using XmlSerializer to deserialize the XML into a class containing the StepXaml property.  Currently when I deserialize the XML, the `<StackPanel>` is being deserialized into its own node.

Is there a way to prevent the deserializer from trying to drill down into `<StackPanel>`, but rather have everything between `<StepXaml>` & `</StepXaml>` returned as one object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by wrapping the XAML code in a CDATA block like so:

```
    <StepXaml>
        <![CDATA[<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:CallTracker.Library.UserControls.BaseUserControls;assembly=CallTracker.Library">
            <uc:LabelValueControl Label="TestLabel2" Value="356738124315" />
          </StackPanel>]]>
    </StepXaml>
```

I then extract this to an object that I can use in a `ContentControl` as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987058/wpf-store-xaml-in-property-and-display-in-contentcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you define a class for your `CallStep` element like this:

```
public class CallStep
{
    //XmlElement attribute is not needed, because the name of the 
    //property and the XML element is the same
    public XmlDocument StepXaml { get; set; }
}
```

then call deserialization like this:

```
//xml is a string containing the XML from your question
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CallStep));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    CallStep cs = (CallStep)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Then `cs.StepXaml` will be a XmlDocument containing this:

```
  <StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:CallTracker.Library.UserControls.BaseUserControls;assembly=CallTracker.Library">
    <uc:LabelValueControl Label="TestLabel" Value="356733" />
  </StackPanel>
```