# WPF: Store XAML in Property and Display in ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentcontrol

I am deserializing a XML file into a class and then trying to display some XAML (stored in a property in the class) in a ContentControl.

Here is my XML:

```
<CallSteps>
  <CallStep>
    <StepID>20</StepID>
    <StepName>Intro</StepName>
    <StepXaml>
        <![CDATA[<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:CallTracker.Library.UserControls.BaseUserControls;assembly=CallTracker.Library">
            <uc:LabelValueControl Label="TestLabel" Value="356733" />
          </StackPanel>]]>
    </StepXaml>
  </CallStep>

  <CallStep>
    <StepID>30</StepID>
    <StepName>Intro</StepName>
    <StepXaml>
        <![CDATA[<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:CallTracker.Library.UserControls.BaseUserControls;assembly=CallTracker.Library">
            <uc:LabelValueControl Label="TestLabel2" Value="356738124315" />
          </StackPanel>]]>
    </StepXaml>
  </CallStep>
</CallSteps>
```

This correctly deserializes to a collection of `CallStep` objects.  Here is what a single `CallStep` object looks like:

[image]

As part of my code I have a `CurrentCallStep` which contains a single `CallStep`.  I would like to display the XAML contained in `StepXaml` within a `ContentControl` (or some other container) using something like:

in VM:

```
/// <summary>
/// Current call step object
/// </summary>
public CallStep CurrentCallStep
{
    get { return _CurrentCallStep; }
    set
    {
        _CurrentCallStep = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.CurrentCallStep);
    }
}
private CallStep _CurrentCallStep;
```

in View:

```
<!-- CurrentCallStep contains the XAML for the current call steps to be displayed -->
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentCallStep.StepXaml}"
                Background="LightBlue"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

This however is not converting the XAML to XAML but rather just showing the text like:

[image]

How can I get the text in `CurrentCallStep.StepXaml` to convert to XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by extracting the CDATA value from each `StepXaml` as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Step XAML
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("StepXaml")]
    public object StepXaml
    {
        get { return _StepXaml; }
        set 
        {
            if (_StepXaml != value)
            {
                object _obj;
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Convert the text into a byte array so that 
                    // it can be loaded into the memory stream.
                    XmlNode _node = (value as XmlNode[])[0];
                    if (_node is XmlCDataSection)
                    {
                        XmlCDataSection _cDataSection = _node as XmlCDataSection;
                        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_cDataSection.Value);


                        // Write the XAML bytes into a memory stream.
                        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                        // Reset the stream's current position back 
                        // to the beginning so that when it is read 
                        // from, the read begins at the correct place.
                        stream.Position = 0;

                        // Convert the XAML into a .NET object.
                        _obj = XamlReader.Load(stream);

                        _StepXaml = _obj;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.StepXaml);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private object _StepXaml;
```

The `ContentControl` simply refers to the `StepXaml` like:

```
    <!-- CallContent contains the XAML for the current call steps to be displayed -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentCallStep.StepXaml}"
```

Doing it this way I didn't have to do anything special while deserializing the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `XamlServices.Load()` to deserialize the string from XAML to a `FrameworkElement`. The property that is bounnd to should be a `FrameworkElement` reference, not a `string` reference.